# Google cloud messaging server api key. What are the IPs needed exactly?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services

Im trying to register a new api key for the google cloud messaging for my android app. It asks for the IP addresses to whitelist.

I must be completely clueless because I don't understand what exactly they are looking for in IP. If this key is used by android devices, what exactly are the IPs I need to be entering?

I can't seem to find proper documentation anywhere.

I'm developing using android studio and there is basically no full documentation from start to finish on the process of adding an app engine backend using endpoints with cloud messaging and then deploying this new backend using android studio.

When I deploy also, it gives me a weird error "Toolkit not found: apple.awt.CToolkit".

Any help is appreciated. I have been researching this for days with no results.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a full documentation from start to finish [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints) I found them very helpful.
As for the IPs the documentation states

> you can use the supplied "0.0.0.0/0" IP address for testing purposes.

This should be changed for security reasons when going into production, it allows connections only from the specified IP of your server.

Check out  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400831/gradle-swingbuilder-toolkit-not-found-apple-awt-ctoolkit-error) as regards your `Toolkit not found: apple.awt.CToolkit` error